# Matching all filenames with given extensions, except a specific filename

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regex:

```
^((?!.*/gradle-wrapper\.jar$)|(.*\.jar$)|(.*\.exe$))
```

and the following data:

```
rupe-engine/src/main/groovy/com/rupe/engine/JongoAutoConfiguration.java

gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

gradle/wrapper/gradle-bundle.exe

gradle/wrapexe/gradle.git

testit.jar
```

Expected result:

Match `gradle/wrapper/gradle-bundle.exe` and `testit.jar`.

Actual result:

Also matching `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`, despite me trying to "black-list" this filename.

Comment: What is the logic you want to implement? What's your data? Is it a big string or an array of strings?

Comment: @scphantm I have tried to re-word your title/question to make it more understandable. Please review my changes, and re-edit if necessary. In future, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a summary on what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is "malfunctioning" because you use a lookahead as an alternative branch, and it is thus not restricting the pattern any longer.

You seem to want to match strings that end with `.jar` or `.exe` and that do not end with `/gradle-wrapper.jar`. Use

```
^(?!.*/gradle-wrapper\.jar$).*\.(?:jar|exe)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DcJLrz/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!.*/gradle-wrapper\.jar$)` - fail the match if after any 0+ chars (`.*`) there is `/gradle-wrapper.jar` substring immediately followed with the end of string (`$`)
- `.*\.` - match any 0+ chars (well, other than line break chars) up to the last `.`
- `(?:jar|exe)` - either `jar` or `exe`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Damn, i was close.  Thank you so much.  In another 20 years i may figure out regex.

Comment: @scphantm: If you have not done that yet, do all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), read through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). A [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is also a great site, you may learn a lot about how lookarounds work there.

Comment: @scphantm: If the answer turned out helpful to you, please consider also upvoting.